# Как распарсить Json, пришедший от response

Tags: java, android, json, vkontakte-api

Делаю String jsonStr = response.json(), чтобы получить данные с ApiVk
В итоге я получаю

```
String jsonStr = "{\"response\":{\"count\":254,\"items\":[{\"last_name\":\"Екимов\",\"id\":325813465,\"first_name\":\"Артём\"},{\"last_name\":\"Виноградов\",\"id\":448209461,\"first_name\":\"Дэнчик\"},{\"last_name\":\"Κонстантинов\",\"id\":444441827,\"first_name\":\"Κонстантин\"}]}}";
```

Как мне распарсить строчку, чтобы получить массив значений id

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
name = jsonObj.getString("id");выдает исключение
first = jsonObj.getJSONObject("items").getString("id");
```

выдает исключение nullpointer

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо разобраться со структурой. Советую сайт https://jsoneditoronline.org

```
{
  "response": {
    "count": 254,
    "items": [
      {
        "last_name": "Екимов",
        "id": 325813465,
        "first_name": "Артём"
      },
      {
        "last_name": "Виноградов",
        "id": 448209461,
        "first_name": "Дэнчик"
      },
      {
        "last_name": "Κонстантинов",
        "id": 444441827,
        "first_name": "Κонстантин"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Из этого видно, что для начала надо обратиться к корневому элементу **response**, потом к массиву **items**. В итоге нужно как то так

```
name = jsonObj.getJSONObject("response").getJSONArray("items")[0].getString("id")
```

Answer (score -1):

regex'ом можно
вот, смотри: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/4CJsOp/1/)
вот сам regex (без экранирования): {\s+"last_name":\s+"?([^"]+)"?,\s+"id":\s+(\d+),\s+"first_name":\s+"?([^"]+)"?\s+}
выполняешь метод парсинга, в результате получишь класс с совпадениями
last_name - [1]
id - [2]
first_name - [3]
[image: результаты парсинга]
[image: результаты парсинга]